# How to include row & col names in image() R

Tags: r, image

I am wondering how you are supposed to include row & column names in an image() plot (base R). I tried just assigning these row & col names to the matrix I am plotting (which normally works e.g. for barplot()) but it didn't work. I have a hunch it is related to par() or xaxs/yaxs arguments...

For Example:

```
# fixes 90-degree rotation
image.real = function(mat) image(t(mat)[,nrow(mat):1])

A = matrix(runif(4),2,2)
colnames(A) = 1:2
rownames(A) = 1:2

image.real(A)
```

Produces:

[image]

Whereas I would like it have the columns and rows labeled the same way as it is when you print the matrix `print(A)`:

```
          1         2
1 0.7572636 0.1607984
2 0.5394689 0.4635099
```

I'm looking for an elegant solution please.

P.S. Bonus points if you can give some practical advise about using image() in R without going mad due to 90-degree rotation. I currently define my own function which 'fixes' this behavior:

`image.real = function(mat) image(t(mat)[,nrow(mat):1])`

but I would love to know if there is a better way!

Comment: Please give more details, including an example of the kind of matrix you want to plot.  Normally you'd use `image()` for a large matrix where it wouldn't make sense to label rows and columns; how big are yours?

Comment: I edited the question, I am looking on a small enough scale where the individual rows & columns are relevant.

Comment: Please post an example of the kind of matrix you want to plot, *in R code*, not descriptively.  You can use `dput()` if you have a matrix in hand, or generate a fake one.

Comment: For your question to be acceptable on SO, it generally needs to "include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem."

Comment: You mean explicitly in code? I did specify the desired behavior...

Comment: Alright I gave an explicit coded example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display a matrix in the order in which it's printed instead of the order in which `image()` displays it, then your function looks fine.  Here's a modification of it that adds labels.  No sanity checks, so if your matrix is missing row names or column names it probably won't do what you want.

```
image.real <- function(mat) { 
  mat <- t(mat)[,nrow(mat):1]
  image(mat, axes = FALSE)
  axis(1, at = seq(0, 1, length = nrow(mat)), labels = rownames(mat))
  axis(2, at = seq(0, 1, length = ncol(mat)), labels = colnames(mat))
  box() 
}
```

Example:

```
x <- matrix(1:6, nrow = 2)
rownames(x) <- c("r1", "r2")
colnames(x) <- c("c1", "c2", "c3")
image.real(x)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know how to make the labels appear orthogonal to the axis though? I find when the names become slightly too long them being in the orientation you gave becomes illegible.

Comment: I suggested an edit that will fix this, apparently you only need to add par(las=2) below the image() function.